# Maintaining relative percentage increases with constraints on max and min values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Good morning,

I'm building a scoring model and I need to have scores that go from a minimum of 50 to a maximum of 400. I have to come up with 15 scores. Their values don't matter as long as the minimum score is equal to 50 and the maximum score is equal to 400.

I also know the percentage increase I would like the scores to have moving from one to the following, which is as follows:

[image]

Let y1=50 and y15=400

The thing is that, if I do:

50*(1+1)=100
then:
100*(1+.5)=150 
...
and then continue all the way down, I'm not constrained to 400 anymore and my maximum score approaches 500. Is there a way where I can maintain the relationships between the scores increases as depicted in the above table while ensuring that my y15=400?

Comment: Did you try a different starting point?  This would include altering the $100$% point to something like $80$%, etc.

Comment: Yeah I could but there's gotta be a way of reducing the percentage increases proportionally to one another so that $Y{15}=400$ isn't it?

Comment: There is, I'm considering the proper mathematical approach...

Comment: To go from $50$ to $400$ you need $(1+1.00)(1+0.50)\dots(1+0.01)=\frac {400}{50}=8$  You can set up a cell in your spreadsheet to compute this, then twiddle the percentages until you hit $8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen a distribution similar to $\dfrac 1x$ as percentage increases, i.e., $\dfrac 11=100\text{%},\dfrac 12=50\text{%}$ and so on.  A totally-proportionate change would be to find some number $a$ such that your percentages are now $\dfrac a1,\dfrac a2,\dfrac a3,\dots,\dfrac a{14}$.  With a spreadsheet, I found that $a\approx 0.737998$ yields a highest score of $400$.

The new percentages look something like

$$74\text{%}\\36\text{%}\\24\text{%}\\18\text{%}\\15\text{%}\\12\text{%}\\10\text{%}\\9\text{%}\\8\text{%}\\7\text{%}\\7\text{%}\\6\text{%}\\5\text{%}\\5\text{%}$$

Algebraically, we have $c,c\cdot (1+a), c\cdot (1+a)\cdot \left(1+\frac a2\right),c\cdot (1+a)\cdot \left(1+\frac a2\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac a3\right),\dots$

If you are concerned about getting later percentages closer to $1\text %$ a different distribution would be required, perhaps something like $\dfrac 1{x^b}$ with a solution of $b\approx 1.2608613$.

Comment: I think mathematically what you did is the right way to do it. I was hoping that I could somehow reduce each percentage by a certain amount in order to get the top score to 400 but looks like I can't. I care about maintaining the percentages as I posted them, so I figured that if I reduce the starting to 400, I get the top to be 400 so i guess I'll do that. Thank you both for your very helpful insights.